# How to parse data stored in child node of Zookeeper /hbase/region-in-transition?

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to find out if any region is going through split by looking at
data in zookeeper.

I triggered a region split manually and captured the data from child Zookeeper
node `/hbase/region-in-transition` which corresponded to the region.

The data looks something like below

```
"ÿ^@^@^@^Tmaster:60000^R!¯^R<83><9d>^OJPBUF^H3^R4bar,,1526471941526.ac8b42de46021dcbf3d597326eb60de1.^X«<8f>ÓÆ¶,"^V
        localhost^PôÔ^C^X÷<84>ÊÅ¶,*^@"
```

But whenever I tried to parse the above data using protobuf class `ClusterStatusProtos.RegionInTransition` , the parsing is failing.

Is there a way to parse this data somehow and determine if this corresponds
to a region in SPLIT or SPLITTING state?

Environment

- Hbase Version - 1.2.0
- Zookeeper - 3.4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in hbase email [thread](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-user/201805.mbox/browser)

> Hi,
>
> Using the above clue I researched further to found out that I need to
>   first use
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.removeMetaData(byte[]
>   data) to remove the metadata and then org.apache.hadoop.hbase.
>   RegionTransition.parseFrom(byte[] data)
>
> Regards, Nand
>
> On Fri, May 18, 2018 at 2:34 PM, Balazs Meszaros <
>   balazs.meszaros@cloudera.com> wrote:
>
> > Hi,
> >
> > HBase parses the binary data in region-in-transition ZooKeeper node with
> >     org.apache.hadoop.hbase.RegionTransition.parseFrom(byte[] data). It is in
> >     the hbase-client jar. These APIs are private, so use them carefully.
> >
> > Best regards,
> >     Balazs
> >
> > On Fri, May 18, 2018 at 5:49 AM Debraj Manna 
> >     wrote:
> >
> > > Hi
> > >
> > > We posted the same in stacker flow.
> > >
> > > [How to parse data stored in child node of Zookeeper /hbase/region-in-transition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50378236/785523)
> > >
> > > We didn't get any reply there also. Anyone any thoughts?
> > >
> > > On Wed 16 May, 2018, 6:54 PM Nand kishor Bansal, 
> > >       wrote:
> > >
> > > > Hi Users,
> > > >
> > > > I'm trying to find out if any region is going through split by looking
> > > >         at
> > > >         data in zookeeper.
> > > >
> > > > I triggered a region split manually and captured the data from child ZK
> > > >         node /hbase/region-in-transition which corresponded to the region.
> > > >
> > > > "ÿ^@^@^@^Tmaster:60000^R!¯^R<83><9d>^OJPBUF^H3^R4bar,,1526471941526.
> > > >         ac8b42de46021dcbf3d597326eb60de1.^X«<8f>ÓÆ¶,"^V
> > > >                 localhost^PôÔ^C^X÷<84>ÊÅ¶,*^@"
> > > >
> > > > But when I tried to parse the above data using protobuf class
> > > >
> > > > ClusterStatusProtos.RegionInTransition, it failed to parse.
> > > >
> > > > Is there a way to parse this data somehow and determine it correspond
> > > >         to a region in SPLIT or SPLITTING state.
> > > >
> > > > I am using HBase 1.2.0 and Zookeeper 3.4.8
> > > >
> > > > Thanks,
> > > >
> > > > Nand